# AlarmManager start alarm at specific time and turn off smartphone

Tags: android, alarmmanager

hello if I create an alarmManager and set it to a specific time and turn off my smartphone, after reboot, is possible application do an old alarm? (my smartphone was off)
I want to know if is it possible to do easily.
thanks!

this is how I set an alarm:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Try.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, TIME, pi);
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible with Broadcast Receiver with BOOT_COMPLETED action and saved parameter for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlarmManager` doesn't keep schedule after reboot. You must manually set it again. In Android, you can do this by receive signal `BootComplete` event, then trigger again `AlarmManager`.

Firstly, you should declare your receiver in manifest file:

```
<!-- permission for using this event -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<!-- declare your receiver -->
<receiver
            android:name="BootCompleteReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And here is code for `BootCompleteReceiver`:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootCompleteReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Received boot completed");
        // trigger your alarm manager here

    }
}
```